# How to get the ASCII value of a character

Tags: python, ascii

How do I get the [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) value of a character as an `int` in Python?

Answer (score 1753, accepted):

From [here](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2005-April/003100.html):

> The function **`ord()`** gets the int value
> of the char. And in case you want to
> convert back after playing with the
> number, function **`chr()`** does the trick.

```
>>> ord('a')
97
>>> chr(97)
'a'
>>> chr(ord('a') + 3)
'd'
>>>
```

In Python 2, there was also the `unichr` function, returning the [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) character whose ordinal is the `unichr` argument:

```
>>> unichr(97)
u'a'
>>> unichr(1234)
u'\u04d2'
```

In Python 3 you can use `chr` instead of `unichr`.

---

[ord() - Python 3.6.5rc1 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord)

[ord() - Python 2.7.14 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord)

Comment: which encoding in chr using ?

Comment: @njzk2: `latin1` (which is not a brilliant thing to do if your original byte was encoded in (say) `cp1251` (Cyrillic)

Comment: Note that chr also acts as unichr in Python 3.  
`chr(31415) -> '窷'`

Comment: @njzk2: it doesn't use any character encoding it returns a bytestring in Python 2. It is upto you to interpret it as a character e.g., `chr(ord(u'й'.encode('cp1251'))).decode('cp1251') == u'й'`. In Python 3 (or `unichr` in Python 2), the input number is interpreted as Unicode codepoint integer ordinal: `unichr(0x439) == '\u0439'` (the first 256 integers has the same mapping as latin-1: `unichr(0xe9) == b'\xe9'.decode('latin-1')`, the first 128 -- ascii: `unichr(0x0a) == b'\x0a'.decode('ascii')` it is a Unicode thing, not Python).

Comment: Why is the function called "ord"?

Comment: @eLymar: it's short for "ordinal," which has similar linguistic roots to "order" - i.e. the numeric rather than symbolic representation of the character

Answer (score 190):

Note that `ord()` doesn't give you the ASCII value per se; it gives you the numeric value of the character in whatever encoding it's in. Therefore the result of `ord('ä')` can be 228 if you're using Latin-1, or it can raise a `TypeError` if you're using UTF-8. It can even return the Unicode codepoint instead if you pass it a unicode:

```
>>> ord(u'あ')
12354
```

Comment: How can you find out which encoding you are using in a given situation?

Comment: @Moustache : In Python3, you'll be using Unicode out-of-the-box.

Comment: Depends on the **object type**.  

Python3 (**str**): `unicode` by default.

Python3 (**bytes**): `str(b'\xc3\x9c', 'ascii')` -> raises _UnicodeDecodeError_.
Python3 (**bytes**): `str(b'\xc3\x9c', 'utf-8')` -> returns _Ü_.

You can also look into the [six](https://six.readthedocs.io/) package.

Answer (score 67):

You are looking for:

```
ord()
```

Answer (score 47):

The accepted answer is correct, but there is a more clever/efficient way to do this if you need to convert a whole bunch of ASCII characters to their ASCII codes at once. Instead of doing:

```
for ch in mystr:
    code = ord(ch)
```

or the slightly faster:

```
for code in map(ord, mystr):
```

you convert to Python native types that iterate the codes directly. On Python 3, it's trivial:

```
for code in mystr.encode('ascii'):
```

and on Python 2.6/2.7, it's only slightly more involved because it doesn't have a Py3 style `bytes` object (`bytes` is an alias for `str`, which iterates by character), but they do have `bytearray`:

```
# If mystr is definitely str, not unicode
for code in bytearray(mystr):

# If mystr could be either str or unicode
for code in bytearray(mystr, 'ascii'):
```

Encoding as a type that natively iterates by ordinal means the conversion goes much faster; in local tests on both Py2.7 and Py3.5, iterating a `str` to get its ASCII codes using `map(ord, mystr)` starts off taking about twice as long for a `len` 10 `str` than using `bytearray(mystr)` on Py2 or `mystr.encode('ascii')` on Py3, and as the `str` gets longer, the multiplier paid for `map(ord, mystr)` rises to ~6.5x-7x.

The only downside is that the conversion is all at once, so your first result might take a little longer, and a truly enormous `str` would have a proportionately large temporary `bytes`/`bytearray`, but unless this forces you into page thrashing, this isn't likely to matter.

Answer (score 7):

To get the ASCII code of a character, you can use the `ord()` function.

Here is an example code:

```
value = input("Your value here: ")
list=[ord(ch) for ch in value]
print(list)
```

Output:

```
Your value here: qwerty
[113, 119, 101, 114, 116, 121]
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy can also be used to get the ascii value of a character. It is particularly useful if you need to convert a lot of characters to their ascii/unicode codepoints. Depending on the number of characters, it could be orders of magnitude faster than calling `ord` in a loop.

To use it, wrap a string/character in a numpy array and view it as `int`, which returns the corresponding numeric value(s) of the character(s) in whatever encoding it is in.

```py
import numpy as np

# if the characters are in a list
lst = ['a', 'ä', 'あ']
ary = np.array(lst).view(int).tolist()   # [97, 228, 12354]


# if the characters are in a string
s = 'abc'
ar = np.array([s])
v = s_arr.view(int)                      # array([97, 98, 99])
```

As a side note: One feature of the view is that if you change the view, the original changes as well. For example, if we want to make all characters in `ar` upper case, we could do so by working on `v`:

```py
v -= 32
print(ar)   # ['ABC']
```