# Python code for calculating number of an alphabet

Tags: python

I need to find the number of an alphabet in the range of alphabets ie a = 1, b=2 , c =3....
So if i get a then the returning value should be 1

Is there a shorter method provided in python(inbuilt) to find it other than declaring a dictionary of 26 alphabets with their respected values.

Please help if you know of such a function.....

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASCII value of a character in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227459/ascii-value-of-a-character-in-python)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [ord()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#ord)

```
>>> c = 'f'
>>> ord(c) - ord('a') + 1
6
```

If you want 'f' and 'F' to both return 6, use lower()

```
>>> c = 'F'
>>> ord(lower(c)) - ord('a') + 1
6
```

You might also be interested in [chr()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#chr)

```
>>> c = 'f'
>>> chr(ord(c) + 1)
'g'
```

Comment: Good answer, just wanted to point out it's case-sensitive.  Might want to add a call to `lower()` to be safe.

Comment: @Laurence: It seems it has been done, although I wouldn't lose too much sleep over it: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2007-October/074991.html

Answer (score 5):

Just:

```
ord(c)%32
```

which can handle both upper and lower.

Comment: While obvious in retrospect, I'd not realized (or remembered) that the `% 32` would work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you only need A to Z then you can use ord:

```
ord(c) - ord('A') + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> alphadict = dict((x, i + 1) for i, x in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase))
>>> alphadict['a']
1
```

Comment: `alphadict = dict(enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase, start=1))`

Comment: @THC4k: that will reverse the key and value.

Comment: @Kabie: Whoops you are right. At least the `start` part is useful.

Answer (score 0):

The function ord('a') will return the numeric value of 'a' in the current text encoding.  You could probably take that and do some simple math to convert to a 1, 2, 3 type mapping.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

```
def lettertoNumber(letter):
    return ord(letter.upper()) - 64
```

**LONG EXPLANATION**

`ord(char)` returns the Unicode number for that character, but we are looking for `a = 1, b = 2, c = 3`.

But in Unicode, we get `A = 65, B = 66, C = 67`.

However, if we subtract 64 from all those letters, we get `A = 1, B = 2, C = 3`. But that isn't enough, because we need to support lower-case letters too!

Because of lowercase letters, we need to make the letter uppercase using `.upper()` so then it automatically can use `ord()` without the result being greater than 26, which gives us the code in the **TL;DR** section.