# How to convert numbers to alphabet?

Tags: python

I read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528982/convert-alphabet-letters-to-number-in-python) about converting the alphabet to numbers but I don't understand how to convert the numbers back into letters.
I would appreciate if someone could expand on that, especially and more specifically, the `chr()` function described in the thread. I've already tried searching for the `chr` function but there aren't many tutorials for it.

Comment: [Here's a link to the documentation of `chr()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr)

Comment: I think this question is not a duplicate because the number `27` is not coverted. It should be for example `AA`

Answer (score 86):

If you have a number, for example 65, and if you want to get the corresponding ASCII character, you can use the `chr` function, like this

```
>>> chr(65)
'A'
```

similarly if you have 97,

```
>>> chr(97)
'a'
```

---

**EDIT:** The above solution works for 8 bit characters or ASCII characters. If you are dealing with unicode characters, you have to specify unicode value of the starting character of the alphabet to `ord` and the result has to be converted using `unichr` instead of `chr`.

```
>>> print unichr(ord(u'\u0B85'))
அ

>>> print unichr(1 + ord(u'\u0B85'))
ஆ
```

**NOTE:** The unicode characters used here are of the language called "Tamil", my first language. This is the unicode table for the same http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0B80.pdf

Comment: You could probably note that, this is an ASCII table specific solution.

Comment: @LaszloPapp You are correct. Considering the thread OP quoted, I assumed that we are dealing with english alphabets.

Comment: Also, you could explain to the readers what the meaning of '7' is. It may not be straight forward.

Comment: @lpapp I edited and clarified it now.