# How to search if a character in a list is in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I cant seem to figure out how to scan through my dictionary to find the characters in cometList and then append the numbers to my numList

i.e: I input comet and cometList becomes (C, O, M, E, T) it would then scan alphabetList and get the corresponding numbers (3, 15, 13, 5, 20) and append them to numList

```
alphabetList = {'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '3', 'D': '4', 'E': '5', 'F': '6', 'G': '7', 'H': '8', 'I': '9', 'J': '10',
                'K': '11', 'L': '12', 'M': '13', 'N': '14', 'O': '15', 'P': '16', 'Q': '17', 'R': '18', 'S': '19',
                'T': '20', 'U': '21', 'V': '22', 'W': '23', 'X': '24', 'Y': '25', 'Z': '26'}
cometList = list(comet)
groupList = list(group)
numList =[]
```

Comment: Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528982/convert-alphabet-letters-to-number-in-python). It might give you a better way to handle things.

Answer (score 2):

```
word = "comet"
codes = [alphabet[letter] for letter in word.upper()]
```

You don't need a list of letters - just iterate the word directly.

Comment: Oh wow that was much simpler then expected, however now when i'm trying to multiply the codes using 
"numComet = reduce(operator.mul, codes)" 
I am getting 'can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Comment: @user3512662 If you want to multiply, the elements of `codes` list must be integers. Do this `codes = [int(alphabet[letter]) for letter in word.upper()]`

Comment: @shaktimaan thank you :) fixed all my errors for this problem  .

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

```
cometList = 'comet'
numList = [alphabetList[letter.upper()] for letter in cometList]
```