# How can you take letters from a string and make them integers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been assigned to create an application that takes a user's first and second name (making sure they're no longer than 10 characters) and calculate their 'lucky name number' based on this grid:

[Lucky Name Number Grid](http://www.playhugelottos.com/uploads/assets/01_News/PlayHuge/PlayHuge.com_LuckyLottoNumbersAndNumerology.PNG)

So for example, John Smith would be:

= (1 + 6 + 8 + 5) + (1 + 4 + 9 + 2 + 8)

= 20 + 24

Then add the digits in each value together:

= (2 + 0) + (2 + 4)

= 2 + 6

= 8 <- Their lucky name number.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
while True:
    first_name = input("What is your first name? ")
    if len(first_name) < 10:
        print("Hello " + first_name + ", nice name!")
        break
    else:
        print("First name is too long, please enter a shorter name.")

while True:
     second_name = input("What is your second name? ")
     if len(second_name) < 10:
         print ("Wow, " + first_name + " " + second_name + " is a really cool name. Let's see how lucky you are...")
         break
     else:
          print ("Second name is too long, please enter a shorter name.")
```

However, I am unsure what my next step would be as I need to take each letter in the name and make it a specific value.

The only way I can think of doing this is by listing each letter with its assigned value like this:

```
A = 1
B = 2
C = 3
D = 4
E = 5
F = 6
G = 7
H = 8
I = 9
J = 1
K = 2
L = 3
M = 4
N = 5
O = 6
P = 7
Q = 8
R = 9
S = 1
T = 2
U = 3
V = 4
W = 5
X = 6
Y = 7
Z = 8

fletter_1 = first_name[0]
fletter_2 = first_name[1]
fletter_3 = first_name[2]
fletter_4 = first_name[3]
fletter_5 = first_name[4]
fletter_6 = first_name[5]
fletter_7 = first_name[6]
fletter_8 = first_name[7]
fletter_9 = first_name[8]
fletter_10 = first_name[9]

print fletter_1 + fletter_2 + fletter_3 + fletter_4 + fletter_5 + fletter_6 + fletter_7 + fletter_8 + fletter_9
```

But this is an extremely long process and not the best way to code.

Please can someone give me some guidance on how I would complete the next step in the best way possible as I am unsure on what to do.

Answer (score 4):

If you haven't heard of the [ASCII table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), it's pretty much a convention of how to represent characters in binary. The function `ord(c)` in python gives you the value of a given character, according to the ASCII table.
I noticed your Lucky Name Number Grid gives the same value every 9 letters, which in math could be represented as `% 9`. Therefore :

```
# ASCII value of A
>>> ord('A') 
65
# Except that we wanted 1 for A
>>> ord('A') - 64
1
# And we also want 1 for J and S
>>> (ord('J') - 64) % 9
1
>>> (ord('S') - 64) % 9
1
>>> (ord('Z') - 64) % 9
8
```

You can use this last formula : `(ord(c) - 64) % 9`

**Edit :** As Loïc G. pointed out, there is a slight error with my formula, due to the modulo function returning 0 from time to time, and your table Grid's indexes starting at 1. Here's the final version :

```
ord(c.lower()) - ord('a')) % 9) + 1
```

`ord('a')` returns `97` (avoiding to hard-code the value), and `c.lower()` makes the function work against lower and upper case characters. The big difference with the first algorithm is that `+ 1` at the end, shifting all indexes by 1 as required by your grid.

Comment: Using `ord()` is a great solution and very efficient, +1.

Comment: @Leb Note that a dictionary lookup is way faster than using `ord` with a subsequent modulo operation.

Comment: @poke that may be true, but with 1 hard-coded value (`64`) against 52 (26 letters + 26 values) on your side, I believe my answer to be a bit more flexible.

Comment: Depends on your definition of flexible. For individual changes, or even additional support for letters, it’s a lot easier than having to figure out additional arithmetic rules for the translation. For example, let’s add some characters from other languages: `äöü`, or a dash `-`.

Comment: As I say in a comment to my answer, `(ord('R') - 64) % 9` returns 0, not 8.

Comment: Thanks @LoïcG. I fixed my algorithm

Answer (score 1):

You should store your grid as a dictionary:

```
luckyNameGrid = {
    'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6, 'g': 7, 'h': 8, 'i': 9,
    'j': 1, 'k': 2, 'l': 3, 'm': 4, 'n': 5, 'o': 6, 'p': 7, 'q': 8, 'r': 9,
    's': 1, 't': 2, 'u': 3, 'v': 4, 'w': 5, 'x': 6, 'y': 7, 'z': 8
}
```

Then, you can use that grid to make the translation into a number (after converting the name to lower-case), and finally, you sum those numbers to get your result:

```
def getLuckyNameNumber (name):
    return sum(map(lambda x: luckyNameGrid[x], name.lower()))
```

Used like this:

```
>>> getLuckyNameNumber('John')
20
>>> getLuckyNameNumber('Smith')
24
```

To make the final conversion, you basically want to calculate the [digit sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digit_sum) of each lucky name number. There are various ways to do that. One would be to conver the number into a string, split for each character, convert the characters back to numbers, and sum those:

```
def getDigitSum (num):
    return sum(map(int, str(num)))
```

An other solution would be to continously divide the number by 10 and sum the remainders. This has the benefit that you don’t need to do type conversions:

```
def getDigitSum (num):
    sum = 0
    while num > 0:
        num, remainder = divmod(num, 10)
        sum += remainder
    return sum
```

For example:

```
>>> getDigitSum(getLuckyNameNumber('John'))
2
>>> getDigitSum(getLuckyNameNumber('Smith'))
6
```

Answer (score 0):

create a dict from letter to value, call it say, D.

then D['A'] = 1 for example

then do this

```
def reduce_value(n):
    return sum(int(i) for i in str(n))

string = "HEYDUDE"
value = sum(D[letter] for letter in string)
while len(str(value)) > 1:
    value = reduce_value(value)
print "final value", value
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is related to [Convert alphabet letters to number in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528982/convert-alphabet-letters-to-number-in-python)

Here is some code to compute the Lucky Name Number:

```
for char in raw_input('Write Text: ').lower():
    print (ord(c.lower()) - ord('a')) % 9 + 1)
```

Or by using list comprehension :

```
print [(ord(c.lower()) - ord('a')) % 9 + 1 for c in raw_input('Write Text: ')]
```

Then, to compute the score, you can use `sum()` buit-in method on the list:

```
print sum([(ord(c.lower()) - ord('a')) % 9 + 1 for c in raw_input('Write Text: ')])
```

Comment: You don't need `value > 9` to use `% 9`, logically : `7 % 9 = 7` so there's no point in checking

Answer (score 0):

```
# example char dictionary with corresponding integer values - use the Numerical Value Chart 
# to get the real values for the whole alphabet. You may need to deal with upper/lower
# case characters
charDict = { 'A' : 1, 'B' : 2, 'C' : 3, 'D' : 4} 

# example names - use your own code here
firstName = 'AAB'
lastName = 'DCDD'

# split the strings into a list of chars
firstNameChars = list(firstName)
lastNameChars = list(lastName)

# sum up values
firstNameSum = 0
lastNameSum = 0
for chr in firstNameChars:
    firstNameSum += charDict[chr]
for chr in lastNameChars:
    lastNameSum += charDict[chr]

# cast sums to strings. In your example, this would be '2024'
combinedNames = str(firstNameSum) + str(lastNameSum)

# split the string into a list of chars
combinedNameDigits = list(combinedNames)

# sum them up
finalSum = 0
for dgt in combinedNames:
    finalSum += int(dgt)

# print the lucky number
print finalSum
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for posting an answer. Please consider adding text to your code to improve your answer.