# More Elegant way to number a list according to values

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I would like to map a list into numbers according to the values.

For example:

```
['aa', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'aa', 'b', 'a'] -> [0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3]
```

I'm trying to achieve this by using numpy and a mapping dict.

```
def number(lst):
    x = np.array(lst)
    unique_names = list(np.unique(x))
    mapping = dict(zip(unique_names, range(len(unique_names)))) # Translating dict
    map_func = np.vectorize(lambda name: d[name])
    return map_func(x)
```

Is there a more elegant / faster way to do this?

Update: Bonus question -- do it with the order maintained.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert alphabet letters to number in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528982/convert-alphabet-letters-to-number-in-python)

Comment: They are not necessarily letters... I mean the general case

Comment: But you also seem to wanting to keep the order looking at the expected sample output that's not achieved with the func `number`, right?

Comment: @Divakar Well at first i didn't worry about that too much. Now i find it worth consideration

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `return_inverse` keyword:

```
x = np.array(['aa', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'aa', 'b', 'a'])
uniq, map_ = np.unique(x, return_inverse=True)
map_
# array([1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0])
```

Edit: Order preserving version:

```
x = np.array(['aa', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'aa', 'b', 'a'])
uniq, idx, map_ = np.unique(x, return_index=True, return_inverse=True)
mxi = idx.max()+1
mask = np.zeros((mxi,), bool)
mask[idx] = True
oidx = np.where(mask)[0]
iidx = np.empty_like(oidx)
iidx[map_[oidx]] = np.arange(oidx.size)
iidx[map_]
# array([0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3])
```

Comment: I do the same thing and `map_` prints as `array([1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0])`

Comment: any idea how to apply this row-wise for a 2d matrix?

Comment: @Josh.F Do you mean looking for unique rows? Then you can use the `axis` keyword of `np.unique`. Or do you mean process each row separately? In that case--if you want to use this solution--you'd have to loop over rows. Or you could look at one of the other answers. Maybe @Divakar's could be fully vectorized in that case?

Comment: The second one, where each row has `np.unique(..., return_inverse=True)` applied to it (or something to the same effect), I'll take a look at his solution, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a vectorized NumPy based solution -

```
def argsort_unique(idx):
    # Original idea : http://stackoverflow.com/a/41242285/3293881 by @Andras
    n = idx.size
    sidx = np.empty(n,dtype=int)
    sidx[idx] = np.arange(n)
    return sidx

def map_uniquetags_keep_order(a):
    arr = np.asarray(a)

    sidx = np.argsort(arr)
    s_arr = arr[sidx]

    m = np.concatenate(( [True], s_arr[1:] != s_arr[:-1] ))
    unq = s_arr[m]
    tags = np.searchsorted(unq, arr)
    rev_idx = argsort_unique(sidx[np.searchsorted(s_arr, unq)].argsort())
    return rev_idx[tags]
```

Sample run -

```
In [169]: a = ['aa', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'aa', 'b', 'a'] # String input

In [170]: map_uniquetags_keep_order(a)
Out[170]: array([0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3])

In [175]: a = [4, 7, 7, 5, 4, 7, 2]                 # Numeric input

In [176]: map_uniquetags_keep_order(a)
Out[176]: array([0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use sets to remove duplicates:

```
myList = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b']
mySet = set(myList)
```

Then build your dictionary using comprehension:

```
mappingDict = {letter:number for number,letter in enumerate(mySet)}
```

Comment: Note that sets don't have a guaranteed order, so this won't necessarily map a -> 0, b -> 1, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that np.unique may be quicker but in fact it's not the case.

Comment: you can still have an ordered set with installing a python package https://pypi.python.org/pypi/orderedset

Answer (score 0):

I did it using the ASCII values because it is easy and short.

```
def number(list):   
    return map(lambda x: ord(x)-97,list)  
l=['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b']  
print number(l)
```

Output:

> [0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1]

Comment: Please show me a solution for general cases but not limited to letters.

Comment: At that time your question was different so I thought it was only for alphabet. I  am trying for that.

Answer (score 0):

If the order is not a concern:

```
[sorted(set(x)).index(item) for item in x]

# returns:
[1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0]
```

Comment: not the best solution but I don't think it deserves a down vote.