# how to write if-elseif conditions in short forms using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

in general if-else condtional statements
if my given input is alphabet (A-Z). so my output should represent from (0-25)
ex: if my input is 'A' then it should return 0
if my input is 'B' the it should return 1 soon....
if my input is 'Z' the it should return 25.

```
if key=='a':
    return 0
elseif key=='b':
    return 1
elseif key=='c':
    return 2
elseif key=='d':
    return 3
elseif key=='e':
    return 4
```

but i want to know is there any alternate way to write this code in python3?
1 or 2 lines of code can be apperciated.

Comment: This is a duplicate post.
please refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802726/putting-a-simple-if-then-else-statement-on-one-line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert alphabet letters to number in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528982/convert-alphabet-letters-to-number-in-python)

Comment: Briefly: `return ord(key.lower()) - ord('a')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you are referring to a [Ternary](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html) operator.

```
'true' if True else 'false'
```

Just in case if it helps, instead of using multiple if, elif conditions, you can keep the data in a python dictionary and map the keys, values based on input.

```
alphaNum = {'a': 0, 'b':1, 'c':2, 'd':3}

user_input = input('Enter an alphabet: ')

if user_input in alphaNum.keys():
    print(alphaNum[user_input])
```

Comment: is it possible in reverse like if my input is 1 it should return A

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You need to map the user input with the values in the dictionary and return the respective key. `for alpha, num in alphaNum.items(): 
    if num == 3:
        print(alpha)`

Comment: Don't use the call to the `keys` method if you don't need to. `if user_input in alphaNum.keys():` could be written as `if user_input in alphaNum:`. And of course according to the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) `alphaNum` should be named `alpha_num` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can also define your values in dictionary and then return by key

```
def example(key):
    tmp_dict = {'a':0,
                'b':1,
                'c':2,
                'd':3,
                'e':5}
    return tmp_dict[key]

print (example('a'))
```