# Mapping alphabets to its numeric equivalent?

Tags: python, pandas

Please see my code below. I'm iterating through strings like '1A', '4D', etc, and I want the output to instead be 1.1, 4.4, and so on..see below.

> Instead of 1A I want 1.1, 1B= 1.2, 4A = 4.1, 5D = 5.4, etc...

[Convert alphabet letters to number in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528982/convert-alphabet-letters-to-number-in-python)

```
data = ['1A','1B','4A', '5D','']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Score'])

newcol = []

for col, row in df['Score'].iteritems()
    if pd.isnull(row):
        newcol.append(row)       
    elif pd.notnull(row): 
        newcol.append(#FIRST ELEMENT OF ROW, 1-5,'.', 
                      #NUMERIC EQUIVALENT OF ALPHA, IE, A=1, B=2, C=3, D=4, etc)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use (with @Ch3steR's comment)-

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
dic = {j:str(i) for i,j in enumerate(ascii_uppercase, 1)}
df['Score'].str[:-1] + '.' + df['Score'].str[-1].map(dic)
```

**Output**

```
0    1.1
1    1.2
2    4.1
3    5.4
4    NaN
Name: Score, dtype: object
```

Comment: You could use `enumerate(iterable, 1)` instead for performing addition in each iteration.

Comment: This solution doesn't work when a string is let's say "11B".

Comment: @Ch3steR yes, will have to modify to [:-1] and [-1] indexers..done

Comment: Updated my answer with your answer. Check out the updated timings and benchmarking stats.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.replace`:

```
df['Score'] = df['Score'].str.replace('\D',
              lambda x: f'.{ord(x.group(0).upper())-64}', regex=True)
```

output:

```
  Score
0   1.1
1   1.2
2   4.1
3   5.4
4
```

Answer (score 1):

You could build mapping using [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.maketrans) and [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=maketrans#str.translate), a common recipe for mapping each character to it's output.

- `str.maketrans`

  > This static method returns a translation table usable for str.translate().
- `str.translate`

  > Return a copy of the s where all characters have been mapped through the map which must be a dictionary of Unicode ordinals (integers) to Unicode ordinals, strings or None. Unmapped characters are left untouched.

Use `pd.Series.apply` and pass `str.translate` to it.

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

table = str.maketrans({c: f'.{i}' for i, c in enumerate(ascii_uppercase, 1)})
df['Score'].apply(str.translate, args=(table, ))

# 0    1.1
# 1    1.2
# 2    4.1
# 3    5.4
# 4       
# Name: Score, dtype: object
```

### Timeit results:

#### Benchmarking setup

```
def ch3ster(df):
    table = str.maketrans(
        {c: f".{i}" for i, c in enumerate(ascii_uppercase, 1)}
    )
    return df["Score"].apply(str.translate, args=(table,))


def Vivek(df):
    dic = {j: str(i) for i, j in enumerate(ascii_uppercase, 1)}
    return df["Score"].str[:-1] + "." + df["Score"].str[-1].map(dic)


def mozway(df):
    return df["Score"].str.replace(
        "\D", lambda x: f".{ord(x.group(0).upper())-64}", regex=True
    )


def check(a, b):
    return (a == b).all()


bench = perfplot.bench(
    setup=lambda n: pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "Score": np.arange(n).astype(str)
            + pd.Series([random.choice(ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(n)])
        }
    ),
    kernels=[ch3ster, Vivek, mozway],
    n_range=[10 ** i for i in range(1, 8)],
    xlabel="size of df",
    equality_check=check,
)
```

#### Results

| n | ch3ster | Vivek | mozway |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 0.000138986 | 0.000730289 | 0.000135238 |
| 100 | 0.00018052 | 0.000789941 | 0.00021811 |
| 1000 | 0.000569407 | 0.00126675 | 0.000882363 |
| 10000 | 0.00471242 | 0.00610832 | 0.00777755 |
| 100000 | 0.0578925 | 0.076809 | 0.0871657 |
| 1000000 | 0.604576 | 0.738928 | 0.867847 |
| 10000000 | 6.21429 | 7.11069 | 8.69433 |

[image: bench graph]
When df is large:

- If execution time matters you could use `maketrans + translate` solution.
- Ordering by execution time(lowest time taken to longest time taken) ch3ster < Vivek < Mozway

When df is small (size less than 10K):

- Both mozway's solution and `maketrans` almost take a similar time. `maketrans` being slightly faster.
- Ordering by execution time(lowest time taken to longest time taken) ch3ster < Mozway < Vivek