# Python:Ascii character<->decimal representation conversion

Tags: python, ascii

Hi I need to be able to convert a ascii character into its decimal equivalent and vice-versa.

How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASCII value of a character in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227459/ascii-value-of-a-character-in-python)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
num=ord(char)
char=chr(num)
```

For example,

```
>>> ord('a')
97
>>> chr(98)
'b'
```

You can read more about the built-in functions in Python [here](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html).

Answer (score 4):

Use `ord` to convert a character into an integer, and `chr` for vice-versa.

Answer (score 2):

[`ord`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#ord)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) and [`chr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) [Built-in Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#built-in-functions) of Python. Check the below explanations of those functions from [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/index.html).

[`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord)

> Given a string representing one Unicode character, return an integer representing the Unicode code point of that character. For example, ord('a') returns the integer 97 and ord('€') (Euro sign) returns 8364. This is the inverse of chr().

[`chr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr)

> Return the string representing a character whose Unicode code point is the integer i. For example, chr(97) returns the string 'a', while chr(8364) returns the string '€'. This is the inverse of ord().

So this is the summary from above explanations,

- [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) is the inverse of [`chr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr)
- [`chr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) is the inverse of [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord)

Check this quick example get an idea how this inverse work,

```py
>>> ord('H')
72
>>> chr(72)
'H'
>>> chr(72) == chr(ord('H'))
True
>>> ord('H') == ord(chr(72))
True
```