# binary conversion using python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program in python for a data networking class to read in a file that contains 8 characters such as 00111001 and put it in a packet to then be converted to ASCII. I want to iterate through the packet and if it's a 1 then add the number in the conversation_list =[128,64,32,16,8,4,2,1] according to the index of the for loop. I can't seem to get into any of my if statements.

file contains: 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1

Here is my output:

Accecpable number of arguments

Printing files message on next line

0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1

00111001

['00111001']

here

0

1

0

```
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]

if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    print("Accecpable number of arguments") else:
    print("Wrong number of arguments")
    sys.exit(1)

message_data = open(filename, "r")

message_text = message_data.read()

if len(message_text) == 0:
    print("Mess has zero length, " + filename + "was empty")

print("Printing files message on next line")  
print(message_text)

replace_message = message_text.replace(", ", "") 
print(replace_message)

packets = []

for index in range(0, len(replace_message), 8):
    substring = replace_message[index:index+8]
    packets.append(substring)

print(packets)

conversion_list = [128,64,32,16,8,4,2,1] running_total = 0 

for packets_index, value in enumerate(packets):
    if value[packets_index] == 1:
        running_total + conversion_list[packets_index]
        print(conversion_list[packets_index] + " added")

    if value[packets_index] == 0:
        print(packets_index)
        continue

print (running_total)
```

Comment: You are aware that the `int()` function has an optional `base` argument?

Comment: To add on to what @KlausD. mentions, there's also `chr()` to convert from an integer to a character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I was looking for. I ended up drawing some pictures and finding out I needed to add another for loop in there.

> ```
> import sys
> #stores .py and file being read
> filename = sys.argv[1]
>
> #checks for amount of arguments
> if len(sys.argv) == 2:
>     print("Accecpable number of arguments")
> else:
>     print("Wrong number of arguments")
>     sys.exit(1)
>
> #opens and reads the file
> message_data = open(filename, "r")
> #stores data into object
> message_text = message_data.read()
>
>
> #check if there is any data in the file by the length
> if len(message_text) == 0:
>     print("Mess has zero length, " + filename + "was empty")
>
> print("displaying message form text:", message_text)
>
> #remove commas 
> replace_message = message_text.replace(", ", "") 
> print("replacing all commas: ", replace_message)
>
> packets = []
>
> # puts message into a packet
> for index in range(0, len(replace_message), 8):
>     substring = replace_message[index:index+8]
>     packets.append(substring)
>
> print("packet has been made", packets)
>
> conversion_list = [128,64,32,16,8,4,2,1]
>
>
> running_total = 0
>
> #starting at negative 1 so count starts at 0 for index 
> count = -1
>
> print("\n=========converting to binrary============\n")
>
>
> #iterate through packet element
> for packets_index, value in enumerate(packets):
>     running_total = 0 
>     for char in value :
>        #counter for iterations
>        count += 1
>
>
>        if char == "1" :
>            #add value of conversion)list index to runnin total
>             running_total += conversion_list[count]
>
>          #show user what has been added
>          print(conversion_list[count], "has been added")
>
>        else: 
>            pass
>
> print ("total is: ", running_total)
>
> print("ASCII result for", running_total, "is the character: ",
> chr(running_total))
>
> print("\n==========Data has been sent to an output file============\n") 
> outfile = open("output_task1.txt", "w+" ,
> encoding = "utf-8", newline ="\r\n") 
> outfile.write(chr(running_total))
> ```

Here is the output:

Accecpable number of arguments

displaying message form text: 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1

replacing all commas:  00111001

packet has been made ['00111001']

=========converting to binrary============

32 has been added

16 has been added

8 has been added

1 has been added

total is:  57

ASCII result for 57 is the character:  9

==========Data has been sent to an output file============

Answer (score 0):

As much as I could understand the question

1. You want to convert the binary input to Decimal
2. Convert the decimal to the ASCII char
3. Iterate through the converted list of ASCII char

   1. Here is a Function that calculates the decimal equivalent to given binary number

   def binaryToDecimal(binary):

   ```
   binary1 = binary 
   decimal, i, n = 0, 0, 0
   while(binary != 0): 
       dec = binary % 10
       decimal = decimal + dec * pow(2, i) 
       binary = binary//10
       i += 1
   print(decimal)
   ```

   2. Use the python inbuilt function to convert to ASCII
      refer to this very simple solution by [Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4387163/8884381)
   3. Append all the entries into a list while converting them iterate over them

Comment: Hey @Amit Gupta,

Thank you for your response but I should have mentioned that I did not want to use the inbuilt function.  luckly I have figured it out and will post my solution.