# whats the easiest way of converting a character into its ascii equivalent in python?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASCII value of a character in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227459/ascii-value-of-a-character-in-python)

The method I have applied is mapping the characters in an array . Is there a library for it ?

Comment: You mean transforming "extended" characters into their nearest ASCII representation, i. e. `à` to `a`, `Ä` to `Ae` (or `AE`?) and `ß` to `ss`? This is a hard problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ord()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#ord) — or are you asking for something entirely different?

> Given a string of length one, return
>   an integer representing the Unicode
>   code point of the character when the
>   argument is a unicode object, or the
>   value of the byte when the argument is
>   an 8-bit string. … This is the
>   inverse of `chr()` for 8-bit strings and
>   of `unichr()` for unicode objects.

Comment: chr() is the reverse, by the way.

Comment: @gokoon Yup, the excerpt from the docs says the same :)

Answer (score 1):

```
ord('a')
```

Displays the ascii value, assuming that's what you're asking. If you mean Unicode characters, then that's a bit more tricky - a mapping would be the best way to do it.