# Python Decoder: alphabet to numbers

Tags: python, decode, encode, alphabet

I've just recently started programming in python through an online course, and on one of the assignments we were required to encode a string with rot13. I used the maketrans method and everything is well but I am curious as to how I'd go about "encoding" the alphabet to digits. For example, would I be able to assign the value of each letter in the alphabet to a number? A-Z = 1-26 ? I don't know how to get around using double digits. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASCII value of a character in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227459/ascii-value-of-a-character-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ord()` and `chr()` functions to turn characters to numbers, and vice versa. The numbers for letters and digets correspond to the ASCII standard.

```
>>> ord('A')
65
>>> chr(65)
'A'
```

To turn that to numbers between 1 and 26, subtract 64, or use `ord('@')` (also 64).

Another option is to use the [`string.ascii_uppercase` variable](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.ascii_uppercase), which let you find the 'index' of a letter, 0-based:

```
>>> string.ascii_uppercase.index('B')
1
>>> string.ascii_uppercase.index('C')
2
>>> string.ascii_uppercase[3]
'D'
```

You can use either technique to create a mapping from letter to number, perhaps:

```
>>> letters = {c: i for i, c in enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase)}
>>> letters['M']
12
```

Answer (score 0):

> For example, would I be able to assign the value of each letter in the alphabet to a number? A-Z = 1-26 ?

To encode:

```
>>> ''.join('%02d' % (ord(c) - ord('A') + 1) for c in 'SECRET')
'190503180520'
```

To decode:

```
>>> encoded = '190503180520'
>>> ''.join(chr(int(encoded[i:i+2]) + ord('A') - 1) for i in range(0, len(encoded), 2))
'SECRET'
```