# Faster way to assign numerical value to letters?

Tags: python

I'm trying to read each character from words in a list, and then assign a value to them based on each of the letters in that word. My code is stupidly long, and I'm convinced there must be a shorter way to do it...

```
    for c in tempWord:
        if(c == "A"):
            tempSum += 1
        elif(c == "B"):
            tempSum += 2
        elif(c == "C"):
            tempSum += 3
        elif(c == "D"):
            tempSum += 4
        elif(c == "E"):
            tempSum += 5
        elif(c == "F"):
            tempSum += 6
        elif(c == "G"):
            tempSum += 7
        elif(c == "H"):
            tempSum += 8
        elif(c == "I"):
            tempSum += 9
        elif(c == "J"):
            tempSum += 10
        elif(c == "K"):
            tempSum += 11
        elif(c == "L"):
            tempSum += 12
        elif(c == "M"):
            tempSum += 13
        elif(c == "N"):
            tempSum += 14
        elif(c == "O"):
            tempSum += 15
        elif(c == "P"):
            tempSum += 16
        elif(c == "Q"):
            tempSum += 17
        elif(c == "R"):
            tempSum += 18
        elif(c == "S"):
            tempSum += 19
        elif(c == "T"):
            tempSum += 20
        elif(c == "U"):
            tempSum += 21
        elif(c == "V"):
            tempSum += 22
        elif(c == "W"):
            tempSum += 23
        elif(c == "X"):
            tempSum += 24
        elif(c == "Y"):
            tempSum += 25
        elif(c == "Z"):
            tempSum += 26
```

This is probably a stupid question, but thanks anyway!

Comment: The answer below will do the job.  Also, addition info here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227459/ascii-value-of-a-character-in-python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`ord`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) to calculate the offset of the character from `A`.

```
A = ord('A')
for c in tempWord:
    if 'A' <= c <= 'Z':
        tempSum += ord(c) - A + 1
```

---

```
A = ord('A')
tempSum = sum(ord(c) - A + 1 for c in tempWord if 'A' <= c <= 'Z')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if 'A'<=c<='Z':
    tempsum+=ord(c)-ord('A')+1
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
import string

def assign(word):
    return sum(string.uppercase.index(ch.upper())+1 for ch in word)

print assign('SIMPLE')
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the best advice for this problem is to create a dictionary associating letter to numbers:

```
d = {'A':1, 'B':2 ... }
```

and changing your `if else` nightmare with this:

```
tempSum += d[letter]
```

Now, by looking detailed at your example and the organization, it seems to be that the value to be summed is the position of upper case letters in the alphabet, so a pythonic way could be using the `string` module like this:

```
import string

tempSum += (string.uppercase.index(letter) + 1)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I tend to make a dictionary.  That should perform better than using `.index` on a list, because dict lookup is ~O(1), but `list.index` can take O(n) in the length of the list (say you're always looking up "Z", for example-- you have to scan the entire list.)  It's not as short as using `ord`, but it's more robust.

Depending on how complex the mapping is, you may want to build it in many different ways.  One would be:

```
>>> import string
>>> d = {c: i for i,c in enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase, 1)}
>>> d
{'A': 1, 'C': 3, 'B': 2, 'E': 5, 'D': 4, 'G': 7, 'F': 6, 'I': 9, 'H': 8, 'K': 11, 'J': 10, 'M': 13, 'L': 12, 'O': 15, 'N': 14, 'Q': 17, 'P': 16, 'S': 19, 'R': 18, 'U': 21, 'T': 20, 'W': 23, 'V': 22, 'Y': 25, 'X': 24, 'Z': 26}
```

after which:

```
>>> word = "INCONTROVERTIBLE"
>>> score = sum(d[c] for c in word)
>>> score
201
```

or, if you want to be more tolerant of missing letters, you can use the `.get` method with a default value of 0:

```
>>> word = "THIS IS A TEST"
>>> score = sum(d.get(c,0) for c in word)
>>> score
149
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 5 years old, but it filled the gaps on what I was looking for, so I am sharing the function I made from it.

My goal was to turn Excel columns into numbers, so I could then feed them into a df.drop() function.

Here is the function I built, for up to 2 Chars only, but you could build a loop for infinite str lengths.

```
colNumbers = []

def letterTonumber(col):
    A = ord('A')
    tempSum = sum(ord(l) - A + 1 for l in col if 'A' <= l <='Z')

    return(tempSum)

def colParse(colNumbers, cols):
    for c in cols:
        if len(c) == 2:
            x=26*letterTonumber(c[0])
            y=letterTonumber(c[1])
            n=(x+y)-1
        else:
            n = letterTonumber(c)-1

        colNumbers.append(n)

cols = ['A','Z','AA','BB']
colParse(colNumbers, cols)

print(colNumbers)

>>> 0,25,26,53
```