# Some issue with Unicode encoding

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, unicode

I am trying to open and parse a Json file using python script and write its content into another Json file after formatting it as I want. Now my source Json file has character **/"**
which I want to replace with a **blank**. I don't have any issue in parsing or creating news file only the issue is that character is not getting replaced by blank. How do I do it. Earlier I have achieved the same task but then there was no such character in the document that time.

Here is my code

```
doubleQuote = "\""


try:

    destination = open("TodaysHtScrapedItemsOutput.json","w") # open JSON file for    output
except IOError:
    pass

with open('TodaysHtScrapedItems.json') as f: #load json file
    data = json.load(f)
print "file successfully loaded"
for dataobj in data:
    for news in data[cnt]["body"]:
        news = news.encode("utf-8")
        if(news.find(doubleQuote) != -1): # if doublequotes found in first body tag
        #   print "found double quote"
            news.replace(doubleQuote,"")
        if(news !=""):
            my_news = my_news +" "+ news

    destination.write("{\"body\":"+ "\""+my_news+"\"}"+"\n")
    my_news = ""
    cnt= cnt + 1
```

[image: Here is how the file looks and the quotes near the red marked text should disappear]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str.replace` doesn't change the original string.So you need to assign the string back to `news`.

```
    if(news.find(doubleQuote) != -1): # if doublequotes found in first body tag
    #   print "found double quote"
        news = news.replace(doubleQuote,"")
```

Comment: and that solved my problem but previously in other program I just used to call string.replace and it used to work...now I am confused totally....no matter that solved my problem...thnx

Answer (score 1):

Some things to try:

You should write and read the json files as binaries, so "w" becomes "wb" and you need to add "rb".

You can define your search string as unicode, with:

```
doubleQuote = u'"'
```

You can lookup the integer value of the character with this command.

```
ord(u'"')
```

I get 34 as a response. The reverse function is chr(34). Are the double quotes you are looking for the same double quotes as the json contains? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227459/ascii-value-of-a-character-in-python) for details.

You don't need the if loop to check if news contains the '"'. Doing a replace on 'news' is enough.

Try these steps and let me know if it still doesn't work.

Comment: I tried this...
`doubleQuote = u'"'`
`news.replace(doubleQuote,"")`
but still the same and even changed the mode to "wb"

Comment: without trying to replace, please read the '"' character and print the integer value, as described above. Also, please read the file as binary, too ('rb')

Comment: yes it prints 34 and even changed read mode to 'rb' but still the file contains that character...I think my code finds out the simple double-quotes from the file and replaces them but the ones that are preceded with '\'(like:\") are not replaced...