# Convert list of numbers to characters

Tags: python

I need to convert a list of numbers to a list of corresponding characters. I have tried using the `chr()` function e.g:

```
numlist= [122, 324, 111, 789, 111]
chr(numlist)
```

The problem I am having is that the `chr()` function can only take one argument, and cannot convert lists of numbers to lists of letters. How can I do this?

Comment: You have to be clear on what you want - Do you want string version of the numbers you have i.e. 122 will be '122' or Do you want ASCII/UNICODE characters for the decimal numbers you have?

Comment: May be similar to this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227459/ascii-value-of-a-character-in-python ? It shows both ASCII and UNICODE versions of conversion.

Comment: Sorry, yes I was looking for ASCII or UNICODE characters, I think I have my answer now, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to iterate over `numlist` and convert each item, creating a new list:

```
characters = [chr(n) for n in numlist]   # Use unichr instead in Python 2.
# ['z', 'ń', 'o', '̕', 'o']
```

Comment: If the code above doesnt work, try this -> charList= [str(n) for n in numList]

Answer (score 2):

Try `map` function in `python3`

```
In [5]: list(map(chr,numlist))
Out[5]: ['z', 'ń', 'o', '̕', 'o']
```

Answer (score 0):

for `chr` argument must be in range 0 to 255, as char only handle ASCII ie 8 bit, 2^8 ->256
for greater than 255 one should use `unichr` in python 2.x

```
>>> [ unichr(x) for x in numlist ]
[u'z', u'\u0144', u'o', u'\u0315', u'o']
```

if you apply `chr` in greater than 255, you will get `ValueError`

```
>>> chr(256)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: chr() arg not in range(256)
```

in python 3x:

```
[ chr(x) for x in numlist ]
['z', 'ń', 'o', '̕', 'o']
```