# How do I convert a list of characters into individual character strings in python?

Tags: python, list, ascii

if I have a list like this:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

How can I convert them to characters so I can get the ASCII codes?

Comment: You may refer to the answer given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227459/ascii-value-of-a-character-in-python)

Comment: `resultList = map(ord,list1)`

Comment: There is no such thing as a "character" type in Python.  There are just strings that are one character long.

Answer (score 0):

The [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) function built-in to Python will convert the character into its corresponding ascii code.

```
codes = []
for i in list1:
    codes.append(ord(i)) # convert character into an integer code

# codes will be [97,98,99,100]
```

Comment: Or, `codes = map(ord,list1)`

Comment: @AhsanulHaque Yep, that's an easy way :)

Answer (score 0):

With a list comprehension

```
codes = [ord(char) for char in list1]
```

From [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) doc:

> Given a string of length one, return an integer representing the
>   Unicode code point of the character when the argument is a unicode
>   object, or the value of the byte when the argument is an 8-bit string.

Answer (score 0):

```
asciiCodes = [ord(x) for x in list1]
```