# How to convert variable into integer in python? like in php (int)

Tags: python, type-conversion

I have a variable with value like a ="\x01" from my database, how can I convert it into an integer. I have searched the internet but had no success in finding anything.

Anyone have an idea?

In PHP, there is a build-in module to convert it. Is there any similar module for that function in Python?

Comment: How about `int(a)`...!? It's a bit unclear what exactly the contents of `a` are here and how that should convert to an int.

Comment: @deceze That doesn't work. That byte literal is not a valid integer.

Comment: @chepner That would be the same problem with PHP's `(int)`, so it's rather ambiguous. I also don't trust this to be an actual literal and not some pseudo-notation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASCII value of a character in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227459/ascii-value-of-a-character-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer is to use [`ord()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord).

```
>>> a = '\x01'
>>> ord(a)
1
```

But if performance is what you are looking for then refer [@chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34828368/2932244).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `struct` module for fixed-length values.

```
>>> a = '\x01'
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack("B", a)
(1,)
```

`unpack` always returns a tuple, since you can extract multiple values from a single string.