# Perfect hash function (i.e. no collisions) with same length

Tags: python, hash

I'm looking for a simple hash function that yields no collisions.

I have an alphanumeric sequence (say 16 letter long) and I want each one of them to map to unique hashed value. Ideally, the hashed value is the same length as the original sequence (16 letter long).

Is there a simple python hash function that achieves this?

Comment: You already named it: it's called a "perfect hash function", first described in a paper around 1978, I think.  How did you not find that in your literature search?

Comment: Could it be a simple cipher? i.e. Subtract 5 from the ascii value for each character (and loop to make sure all characters are valid)

Comment: alphanumeric sequences can be stored as strings... which are immutable and therefore hashable. Just use the `str(sequence)`: a `dict = { str(sequence): sequence, ...}` or just `set(str(sequence), ...)`

Comment: Sounds like the identity hash would work just fine. If you want to hash 16-character sequences to 16-character sequences with no collisions, `lambda x: x` satisfies those requirements.

Comment: note: It must return a different value. Cannot always return X if the input to the hash function is X

Comment: @SteveHe what about `s[::-1]`? `s_new = "".join([chr(ord(char) + 1) for char in s])`? That is a different value. If that doesn't work, what consitutes "different enough"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the requirements aren't defined and the questioner pulled out new requirements after otherwise-valid answers were given.

Comment: "Cannot always return X if the input to the hash function is X." Why not? You need to explain why. If this is a security measure, it's incredibly dubious. Why do you need a perfect hash, versus say SHA256?

Answer (score 3):

Use something like

```
u"".join([unichr(ord(spl[0])*100 + ord(spl[1])-30) for spl in [instr[i: i + 2] for i in range(0, 16, 2)]])
```

which is a really crummy shift:

`1234567890123456` becomes `ጸᐂᓌᖖᙖጸᐂᓌ`

`aAzZ09jdmekfADEF` becomes `☇⿤ዛ⦮⫛⨔ᦊᬜ`

`IamBADatREQUIREM` becomes `᳇⪸ᦊ☺ ΊᲸᬣ`

`zzaa009990123456` becomes `〄☧ዒᙟᙖጸᐂᓌ`

which is reversed via:

```
"".join([chr(ord(num) / 100) + chr(ord(num) % 100 + 30) for num in unistring])
```

`u"〄☧ዒᙟᙖጸᐂᓌ"` becomes `zzaa009990123456`

and thus the circle of life is complete.

Answer (score 0):

If the hash function can return any immutable object, return the strings directly. No need to map them into anything.

```
def hash(s):
    return s
```

If it needs to return ints, then it's simple. Python integers can be arbitrarily large, so all you have to do is convert the string an int with the same bytes.

```
def hash(s):
    return int.from_bytes(string.encode(), byteorder='big')
```

Comment: the first one is not acceptable. we cannot always return the original string. it is one of my requirements. let's say for security reason we want to map to some other value

Answer (score 0):

hash functions return a string of fixed length relative to the hash function not the input string, what you want is a cipher

https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/8765/is-there-a-hash-function-which-has-no-collisions

[ASCII value of a character in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227459/ascii-value-of-a-character-in-python)

```
from random import shuffle

def create_cipher():

    key = []
    # ASCII value of numerals
    for i in range(48,58):
        key.append(i)
    # ASCII value of lowercase
    for i in range(65,91):
        key.append(i)
    # ASCII value of uppercase
    for i in range(97,123):
        key.append(i)
    print key
    cipher = list(key)
    shuffle(cipher)
    print cipher
    cipher_dict = {}
    for i in range(len(key)):
        cipher_dict[key[i]] = cipher[i]
    return cipher_dict

def cipher(string,code_dict):

    coded_list = []
    list_string = list(string)
    list_string = [ord(i) for i in list_string]
    for i in list_string:
        coded_list.append(code_dict[i])
    coded_list = [chr(i) for i in coded_list]
    return  ''.join(coded_list)

msg = 'HelloWorld2017'
encode_dict = create_cipher()
decode_dict = {y:x for x,y in encode_dict.iteritems()}
encoded_cipher = cipher(msg,encode_dict)
decoded_cipher = cipher(encoded_cipher,decode_dict)

print msg
print encoded_cipher
print decoded_cipher


>>>
HelloWorld2017
pryyLILoyx9fgm
HelloWorld2017
```

of course you'd want to validate your inputs... for alphanumeric you can use:

```
isalnum()
```