# Filter special characters, count them, and rewrite on another csv

Tags: python, regex, csv, special-characters

I am trying to see if there are special characters in csv. This file consist of one column with about 180,000 rows. Since my file contains Korean, English, and Chinese, I added ``` 가-힣``A-Z``0-9 ``` but I do not know what I should to not filter Chinese letters. Or is there any better way to do this?

Special letters I am looking for are : ■ , △, ?, etc

Special letters I do not want to count are : Unit `(ex : ㎍, ㎥, ℃)`, `()`, `'` etc.

Searching on stackflow, many questions considered designating special letters to find out first. But in my case, that is difficult since I have 180,000 records and I do not know what letters are actually in there. As far as I am concerned, there are only three languages ; Korean, English, and Chinese.

This is my code so far :

```
with open("C:/count1.csv",'w',encoding='cp949',newline='') as testfile:        
    csv_writer=csv.writer(testfile)
    with open(file,'r') as fi:
            for line in fi:
                x=not('가-힣','A-Z','0-9')
                if x in line :
                    sub=re.sub(x,'*',line.rstrip())
                count=len(sub)
                lst=[fi]+[count]
                csv_writer.writerow(lst)
```

---

Using `import re`

```
regex=not'[가-힣]','[a-z]','[0-9]'

file="C:/kd/fields.csv"
with open("C:/specialcharacter.csv",'w',encoding='cp949',newline='') as testfile: 
    csv_writer=csv.writer(testfile)
    with open(file,'r') as fi:
            for line in fi:
                search_target = line
                result=re.findall(regex,search_target)
                print("\n".join(result))
```

Comment: I suggest you look at their ascii or other code, as in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227459/ascii-value-of-a-character-in-python. Then, you will most likely have to manually parse through the characters you do or do not want.

Comment: @Landmaster hmm if I'm not mistaken, your link shows changing letters to int value and adding them up, right? I just need to count occurence of special characters.

Comment: Oh yes yes, the post shows you how to add them, but I'm saying you can convert the characters to unicode or ascii as those are exhaustive, I believe.

Comment: Conversely, you could put all characters in a dictionary and include the action in the dictionary, say {'a': True, '#': False} and then use the True or False to indicate whether you should filter or not.

Comment: @Landmaster Ok. I get it. I will try that method too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know why you consider not filtering chinese characters when you are only looking for some special letters. [This library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zhon) can filter chinese.

1. filter Chinese on top of your filtered list of Korean, English and number: `regex = "[^가-힣a-zA-Z0-9]" result=re.findall(regex,search_target)`
2. filter either 1) a list of special characters that you seek or 2) a list of special characters you want to avoid.

Choose wisely which fits your case better to avoid as much exceptions as possible so that you do not have to add more filters everytime.

Make the list as regex.

Then, loop through your 180,000 rows using regex to filter out the rows.

Update your regex-list until you filter everything.

Comment: Thank you. As I have mentioned above, your first suggestion is time consuming. I think second suggestion is better for me which to count every letters except number, Korean, English, and Chinese. I will try

Comment: Either way, leave anything but special letters first by filtering number, Korean, English, and Chinese.

Comment: Then you can choose to make a list of what you are looking for: ■ , △, ?, etc. or a list of what you do not want to count: Unit (ex : ㎍, ㎥, ℃), (), ' etc.

Comment: To code, I just need to add `Zhon` right? Since it is a separate library, I can't write in one line.

Comment: you need to install zhon http://zhon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installation

Comment: Then you can do re.findall('[%s]' % zhon.hanzi.characters, 'unfilterer_string') to filter

Comment: Okay. I will try it after I am done with refining my dataset. Thanks again

Comment: How can I put `x=not('가-힣','A-Z','1-9')` as a string? When I try my code above, I get `TypeError : 'in<string>' requires string as a left operand, not bool`

Comment: Why do you need it as a string? It's a regex.

Comment: I get an `TypeError` when I try my code. I did not add Zhon part yet.

Comment: Do you know what regex is?

Comment: I edited my question to show what I tried using regex. I googled it to find what it is but still don't know how I can filter special characters.

Comment: You are almost correct. regex = "[^가-힣a-zA-Z0-9]"

result=re.findall(regex,search_target)

Comment: Oh nice. I got it but just one more question. Unless you add ' ' or '\n' into regex, it looks like it filter them too along with special characters, right?

Comment: \n will be filtered because you are reading by line not because of the regex. However, space will not be filtered unless you add it to the constraint.