# Is it possible to check if a Letter is in a Range of the ASCII Alphabet?

Tags: python, ascii

```
USR_PWD = raw_input ("Please Input A 10 Digit Password")
if USR_PWD[0] == chr(range(65,90))
    print "True"
```

Line 2 does not work, I'm attempting to check and see if the input's first character is a capital letter (65 is A and 90 is Z). Not even sure if this is the best way to go about it either. I'm a beginner so I could be making a very easy mistake but, thanks for the help.

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you getting an error? Or are you getting an unexpected or no result?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to use `chr`. Just check the character is between `'A'` and `'Z'`.

```
if 'A' <= USR_PWD[0] <= 'Z':
    print "True"
```

You could also use `if USR_PWD[0].isupper()`, but that also returns true for lots of characters outside the A-Z range, like `Œ`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the ASCII code of a character you can use `ord()`.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227459/ascii-value-of-a-character-in-python).

In this case your code looks like:

```
USR_PWD = raw_input ("Please Input A 10 Digit Password")
if ord(USR_PWD[0]) in range(65,90):
    print "True"
```

Comment: `in range(...)` is a very inefficient way to check if a number falls within a particular range in Python 2. It constructs a list of numbers and iterates through it to find the number you are looking for.

Comment: You are completely right. I only suggested usage of `ord()` because I wanted to point out how it could be done with the original code.