# How to convert a list into ASCII

Tags: python, ascii

How can I convert a list into ASCII, but I want to have a list again after I converted it.

I found this for converting from ASCII to a list:

```
L = [104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 44, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100]
print(''.join(map(chr,L)))
```

But it doesn't work reversed.

This is my input:

```
L = ['h','e','l','l','o']
```

And I want this as output:

```
L = ['104','101','108','108','111']
```

Comment: `print(list(map(chr,L)))` ? So you'll have a list of each char converted to ascii (returns `['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ',', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']`). In fact, your `join` is joining each element of your map using `''` as separator. You don't want to join them if you want `a list again` as you said

Comment: Yes that's my output, but I want to use ord(). Do you know how I do need to do it then?

Comment: You want to use `ord()` to transform your list of integers into list of ascii representation of these integers ? That's not what `ord()` do. Be more specific. Edit your question and say what you want to get as a result. What do you want to use `ord()` for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
L = ['h','e','l','l','o']
print(list(map(str, map(ord, L))))
```

This outputs:

```
['104', '101', '108', '108', '111']
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a much simpler solution:

```
L = ['h','e','l','l','o']
changer = [ord(x) for x in L]
print(changer)
```

Using the function `ord()`

Answer (score 2):

This worked well for me.

```
>>> L = [104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 44, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100]
>>> print [ chr(x) for x in L]
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ',', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
```

Comment: Yes, but I want >>> L=['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ',', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'] and an output of [104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 44, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100]

Comment: print [ ord(x) for x in L]

Answer (score 2):

```
L = ['h','e','l','l','o']

print(list(map(ord,L)))
#output : [104, 101, 108, 108, 111]

print(list(map(str,map(ord,L))))
#output : ['104', '101', '108', '108', '111']
```

Answer (score 1):

This works the other way round:

```
L = ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ',', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
L = [ord(x) for x in L]
print(L)
```

output:

```
[104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 44, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100]
```

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227459/ascii-value-of-a-character-in-python)

You can try:

```
L = ['h','e','l','l','o']
for x in range(len(L)):
     L[x] = ord(L[x])
print(L)
```

Ouput:

```
[104,101,108,108,111]
```

EDIT:

**ord()** allows you to convert from char to ASCII whereas **chr()** allows you to do the opposite

Answer (score 0):

```
message = list(input("Message: "))
message = [ord(x) for x in message]
print(message)
```

Here is my solution for this. Hope this helps! Output depends on your input, but in general it will follow the form

```
[x, y, z]
```