# How to convert ASCII values from a string of strings

Tags: python, tuples, ascii

Is it possible to convert a string of ASCII characters from a list of strings:

`[['You '], ['have '], ['made '], ['my '], ['day.']]`

I understand that the conversion is done using `ord(i)` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227459/how-to-get-the-ascii-value-of-a-character). I just can't seem to figure out how to retain the list of list structure after the conversion that reads something like this:

`[[ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ], etc. ]`

Thank you!

Comment: Are your nested lists always just a single element long?

Comment: You don't need `ord` if you're using Python 3.

Comment: BTW, you have a list of lists, with each inner list containing a string. There are no tuples in that code.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Just revised the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use list comprehension or maps to traverse into the inner elements and apply the `ord` function:

example:

```
# python 3 (py2 syntax slightly different)
x = [['You '], ['have '], ['made '], ['my '], ['day.']]
[list(map(ord, i[0])) for i in x]
# outputs
Out[41]:
[[89, 111, 117, 32],
 [104, 97, 118, 101, 32],
 [109, 97, 100, 101, 32],
 [109, 121, 32],
 [100, 97, 121, 46]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is very helpful. Could you suggest how to implement this into a statement that would enable one to replace all values less than a certain value by None (32 => None), and then subtract the rest of the lists by another value? Something like: if number < 65: q = None, else q = number - 12?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

- Nest your list comprehension:

  ```
  [[ord(c) for c in nested[0]] for nested in outerlist]
  ```
- In Python 3, you can encode the string to a `bytes` object, and convert that to a list. `bytes` objects are just sequences of integers, after all:

  ```
  [list(nested[0].encode('ascii')) for nested in outerlist]
  ```

  The Python 2 equivalent is to use the [`bytearray()` type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray); for `str` (byte strings):

  ```
  [list(bytearray(nested[0])) for nested in outerlist]
  ```

In both cases I assume that your nested list contain just a single element each, a string.

Demo on Python 3.7:

```
>>> l = [['You '], ['have '], ['made '], ['my '], ['day.']]
>>> [[ord(c) for c in nested[0]] for nested in l]
[[89, 111, 117, 32], [104, 97, 118, 101, 32], [109, 97, 100, 101, 32], [109, 121, 32], [100, 97, 121, 46]]
>>> [list(nested[0].encode('ascii')) for nested in l]
[[89, 111, 117, 32], [104, 97, 118, 101, 32], [109, 97, 100, 101, 32], [109, 121, 32], [100, 97, 121, 46]]
```