# XOR two strings of different length

Tags: python-3.x

So I am trying to XOR two strings together but am unsure if I am doing it correctly when the strings are different length.
The method I am using is as follows.

```
def xor_two_str(a,b):
xored = []
for i in range(max(len(a), len(b))):
    xored_value = ord(a[i%len(a)]) ^ ord(b[i%len(b)])
    xored.append(hex(xored_value)[2:])
return ''.join(xored)
```

I get output like so.

```
abc XOR abc: 000
abc XOR ab: 002
ab XOR abc: 5a
space XOR space: 0
```

I know something is wrong and I will eventually want to convert the hex value to ascii so am worried the foundation is wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out what exactly you're looking for.  could you add some expected results?

Comment: @Hoog basically I am wondering if I am xoring two strings of different length correctly. I'm new to this and am unsure if my approach is correct. What my goal is, I am receiving cipher-texts, I xor them together, convert to ascii and decrypt my messages from there. Hope this helps

Comment: @JohnOC Let’s start with: what do you *exactly* mean by “xoring two strings”? Because on the face of it this operation isn’t meaningful. “xor” is an operation on boolean values, or maybe on bit sequences.

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks mostly correct (assuming the goal is to reuse the shorter input by cycling back to the beginning), but your output has a minor problem: It's not fixed width per character, so you could get the same output from two pairs characters with a small (< 16) difference as from a single pair of characters with a large difference.

Assuming you're only working with "bytes-like" strings (all inputs have ordinal values below 256), you'll want to pad your hex output to a fixed width of two, with padding zeroes changing:

```
xored.append(hex(xored_value)[2:])
```

to:

```
xored.append('{:02x}'.format(xored_value))
```

which saves a temporary string (`hex` + slice makes the longer string then slices off the prefix, when format strings can directly produce the result without the prefix) and zero-pads to a width of two.

There are other improvements possible for more Pythonic/performant code, but that should be enough to make your code produce usable results.

Side-note: When running your original code, `xor_two_str('abc', 'ab')` and `xor_two_str('ab', 'abc')` both produced the same output, `002` ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVDBbsMgDL3nK7zDhC2xHNZbpe1HojQyC12ZWohc2qWq@u0ZJOmUcMB6Dz/78bpbPAS/GYbW7qEP0sTf0JyjIGtD2wLSSaxt4QOqeoT7IODAeRD23xZP3OPRemTSkKshmnX/2ubKx4tNE4K0yJV7nfprgt1ImZkyiVorS@4661s82B4Xo6h6386tYuNFPChV/gTnpyYqimyy13DLPitUbL6UhrEkmwv8hKtXyAgU1dM/OnE@olqGc3@Rh4Z8E7x9wv2hyrTxxBHzUr0KMjMpk2H4Aw)), which is what you'd expect (since xor-ing is commutative, and you cycle the shorter input, reversing the arguments to any call should produce the same results). Not sure why you think it produced `5a`. My fixed code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVDRasMwDHzPV2gPwxJ4oXRvhfVHQhrkxd08Wjuo7pYS@u2ZnXQj8YPFnXXS@bpb/Az@dRxbe4Q@SBN/QnOJgqwN7QpIJ7G2hTeo6gkeg4AD50HYf1g8c48n65FJQ66G6KH71zbffLraNCFIi1y557m/JjhMlHlQJlFrZcldZ32Lathttv1dlWn5mSMuxtIsERuv4kGp8is4PzdQUWSzvYZb9luhYvOuNEwl2V3gP7h6hYxAUT3/pxPnI6plSMOT3DXkm@BlD8PCYVqqV4FmJmUzjr8)) just makes the outputs `000000`, `000002`, `000002`, and `00`; padded properly, but otherwise unchanged from your results.

As far as other improvements to make, manually converting character by character, and manually cycling the shorter input via remainder-and-indexing is a surprisingly costly part of this code, relative to the actual work performed. You can do a few things to reduce this overhead, including:

1. [Convert from `str` to `bytes` once, up-front, in bulk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36225223/364696) (runs in roughly one seventh the time of the fastest character by character conversion)
2. Determine up front which string is shortest, and [use `itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to extend it as needed, and `zip` to directly iterate over paired byte values rather than indexing at all

Together, this gets you:

```
from itertools import cycle

def xor_two_str(a,b):
    # Convert to bytes so we iterate by ordinal, determine which is longer
    short, long = sorted((a.encode('latin-1'), b.encode('latin-1')), key=len)
    xored = []
    for x, y in zip(long, cycle(short)):
        xored_value = x ^ y
        xored.append('{:02x}'.format(xored_value))
    return ''.join(xored)
```

or to make it even more concise/fast, we just make the `bytes` object without converting to hex (and just for fun, use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)+[`operator.xor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.xor) to avoid the need for Python level loops entirely, pushing all the work to the C layer in the CPython reference interpreter), then convert to hex `str` in bulk with [the (new in 3.5) `bytes.hex` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex):

```
from itertools import cycle
from operator import xor

def xor_two_str(a,b):
    short, long = sorted((a.encode('latin-1'), b.encode('latin-1')), key=len)
    xored = bytes(map(xor, long, cycle(short)))
    return xored.hex()
```