# Converting each individual letter of a string to ASCII equivalent - Python

Tags: python, ascii

How would one write a code to display the conversion of individual letters in a string to it's ASCII equivalent? One example of the output in shell would look like this:

```
Enter a 3-letter word: Hey
H = 72
e = 101
y = 121
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the ASCII value of a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227459/how-to-get-the-ascii-value-of-a-character)

Comment: You can use `ord` to get ascii equivalent of the character. And `chr` to convert ascii value to character.

Answer (score 0):

Use built-in `ord` function

```
>>> ord('H')
72
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the input, and print each character plus its ordinal value.

```py
user_input = input("Enter a 3-letter word: ")
for character in user_input:
    print(character + " = " + ord(character))
```