# Python: Convert list of numbers to according letters

Tags: python, string, numpy

I know the answer is going to be obvious once I see it, but I can't find how to convert my output list of numbers back to letters after I've manipulated the list.

I am putting in data here:

```
import string

print [ord(char) - 96 for char in raw_input('Write Text: ').lower()]
```

and I want to be able to reverse this so after I manipulate the list, I can return it back to letters.

```
example: input gasoline / output [7, 1, 19, 15, 12, 9, 14, 5]
```

manipulate the output with append or other
then be able to return it back to letters.

Everything I search is only to convert letterst to numbers and nothing to convert that list of numbers back to letters.

Thank you!

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227459/how-to-get-the-ascii-value-of-a-character), where a similar question has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done by using `chr()` built-in function :

```
my_list = [7, 1, 19, 15, 12, 9, 14, 5]
out = ""
for char in my_list:
    out += chr( 96 + char )
print(out) # Prints gasoline
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the final output as a list of characters use the first one otherwise the last one.

`l = [7, 1, 19, 15, 12, 9, 14, 5] # l is your list of integers
listOfChar = list(map(chr,[x+96 for x in l]))
aWord = "".join(list(map(chr,[x+96 for x in l])))#your word here is "gasoline"`