# How to print each letter of ASCII VALUE

Tags: python, ascii

Hi everyone I was just exploring through ASCII in python. But the thing is i cannot find the ASCII value by each letter of the entered value With its corresponding letter. I was just able to find ASCII with number only.
Suppose let me just ask how do i get the result in the following way.
A program that ask the user to enter their first name. The program then prints each
letter of the user’s first name along with the corresponding ASCII value.
Suppose the entered value is TAN than the output should be like below.
T 116
A 97
N 110

Comment: The function you are looking for is called [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord). If you need more help then you will need to try to write a little code and ask a more specific question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the ASCII value of a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227459/how-to-get-the-ascii-value-of-a-character)

Answer (score 1):

In order to find the ASCII value of a character use the builtin function `ord` and in order to get the charecter from the value use `chr`

```
ord("a")
```

would give you 97 and

```
chr(97)
```

would give you 'a'

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
>>> import string
>>> string.ascii_letters
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
>>> for ch in string.ascii_letters :
...     print ch, ord(ch),
... 
a 97 b 98 c 99 d 100 e 101 f 102 g 103 h 104 i 105 j 106 k 107 l 108 m 109 n 110 o 111 p 112 q 113 r 114 s 115 t 116 u 117 v 118 w 119 x 120 y 121 z 122 A 65 B 66 C 67 D 68 E 69 F 70 G 71 H 72 I 73 J 74 K 75 L 76 M 77 N 78 O 79 P 80 Q 81 R 82 S 83 T 84 U 85 V 86 W 87 X 88 Y 89 Z 90
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ord()` to do so. Here is the code that would do so:

```py
name = input()
#name = "TAN"
for i in name:
  print(i, end = " ")
  print(ord(i), end = " ")
```

Output:

```
T 116 A 97 N 110
```

Comment: Taking input is very easy so I did not write code for that, however, I will edit it

Answer (score 0):

You could use ord() function.

```
s = input("Enter your name : ") 
for char in s:
    print(f"{char} {ord(char)}", end="\t")
```

#### Output

```
Enter your name : Albus Percival Wulfric Brian Dumbledore
A 65    l 108   b 98    u 117   s 115     32    P 80    e 101   r 114   c 99    i 105   v 118   a 97    l 108     32    W 87    u 117   l 108   f 102   r 114   i 105   c 99      32    B 66    r 114   i 105   a 97    n 110     32    D 68    u 117   m 109   b 98    l 108   e 101   d 100   o 111   r 114   e 101
```

Comment: Thats basic. Code changed