# Can I use integers to use a unicode in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

I have a slight problem that may be unsolvable in python.
Can you use an integer variable to type unicode in python? For example, let's say you have a variable: `variable = 0041`. Can you do something like (without having to manually type it) get `\u0041` (`a`)?
I have not really tried anything because nothing comes to mind when I try to solve this problem. If there is a possible solution, what is it?

Sorry if the answer is painfully obvious or I did not provide enough information, I'm new to this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the ASCII value of a character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227459/how-to-get-the-ascii-value-of-a-character)

Comment: Note that `variable = 0041` won't work, leading zeros aren't allowed.  Even if you removed them the number is interpreted as decimal, not hex.  You could use `variable = 0x41`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the `chr` function is for.

```
>>> chr(int('0041', 16))
'A'
```