# Convert js fromCharCode to python native code

Tags: javascript, python-3.x

How can i convert this function to python native code

```
function replac_ch(a) {
    return a.replace(/[A-Za-z]/g, function (a) {
        return String.fromCharCode(a.charCodeAt(0) + ('M' >= a.toUpperCase() ? 13 : - 13))
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried anything in python yet?

[re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) is the regex library.

to make something uppercase use [string.upper()](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/upper.html)

The [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/394814/1586014) is: 13 if 'M' >= a.upper() else -13

anonymous functions use [lambda](https://realpython.com/python-lambda/)

You can use [char() and ord()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227459/how-to-get-the-ascii-value-of-a-character) to move from char code to character and vice versa.

Comment: i tried this code a = 'sa'  a_r = ord(a[0])+(13 if 'M' >= a.upper() else -13)

Comment: a = 'sa'  a_r = ord(a[0])+(13 if 'M' >= a.upper() else -13) ss = chr(a_r)

Comment: how can i make the lsat part a.replace(/[A-Za-z]/g,ss)

Comment: Your javascript code is a function. The basic structure for a function in python is:

def replac_ch(a){

}

Comment: i break it down this a.replace(/[A-Za-z]/g,String.fromCharCode(a.charCodeAt(0) + ('M' >= a.toUpperCase() ? 13 : - 13)))
give 'ff'

Answer (score 0):

this is how i solve it the same result from js and python

```
import re

text = "1.w-952168.1.2.PzaDdMBdaBowPJvNa68GYQ,,.vgNsGnZefWSfDD1ygFFWXKcTstrPc68-aL1DNHU9XsiSEGo8fWBAGTuIWNliaXx-cqaeOIBvq8YrgzYjbGk6BrB8MhrCSy1YJKFhV8il-MG94tXPPbpHiSePsqYOBcARhnHVh968P2152H8Pc8o1Eu10lMUR5_jB-1UX5-wQSzUToSndof66nlwcaAi7KqdgRUvXbT6iLuHOXO2GsuJ1bE3Gv3KIT0qE2eWCNBGgwtuD1yoWVA2sXqnULl62aauc"
    
    
    def replac_ch(text):
        val = []
        for i in text:
            val.append(re.sub(r"[A-Za-z]", chr(ord(i[0])+(13 if 'M' >= i.upper() else -13)), i))
        return ''.join(val)
        
    print(replac_ch(text))
```